# keyboard overplay input text in few android devices react native expo app

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Hi I'm having an giftedchat input text overlap issue when keyboard is visible on few android devices to resolve this i tried to use keyboard-show/hide method but didn't worked also tried to using keyboard-spacer but nothing worked.
This issue is not replicating on very devices currently its happening on One plus 6, samsung A-70 android version 9 Oxygen OS 9.0.9.
The exact issue it not completely overlapping the input text let say only bottom border is getting under the keyboard.
please find below the image to get exact idea of the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android'){
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.input}>
                //your <GiftedChat/> tag
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
input: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 45,
    marginBottom: 10,

},
```

});

### UPDATE

Go through this link : 
[Keyboard issue #435](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/435#issuecomment-361577462)

Comment: better you provide some comments on how to fix the issue using the code you provided